# Number of ways to fit small interval inside a big interval

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have `x` steps represented in my diagram. What's the most efficient way of working out how many lengths of `y` fit into my steps, incrementing forward, 1 step at a time.

Example:

```
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ <= 8 steps (x)
-------         <= 4 steps in length (y)
  -------
    -------
      -------
        -------
        ^
        result: 5 y fit into x
```

I have a rather silly way of solving my problem, given the example above:

```
8 - 4 = 4
7 - 4 = 3
6 - 4 = 2
5 - 4 = 1
4 - 4 = 0 <= when we hit 0, we count the total, which is 5.
```

What's a better way of working this out? I might also want to know how many lengths of `3` fit into `8` and would be expecting an answer of `6`.

My maths is not great and I need to code this, so a simple explanation would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You asked about terminology: I'm not sure of a better name to give this than *subtraction* or "fitting a small interval inside a bigger one", but I can tell you that this is not the same as permutations. A permutation is a rearrangement of a set of objects; for example, the number of permutations of the letters in HAT is $6$, since we have AHT, ATH, HAT, HTA, TAH, THA. As you can see, this is not what you're looking for in your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer will simply be $x-y+1$, since the smaller blocks can start at position $0, 1, \ldots, x-y$.

Comment: Right you are - I'm pretty sure I thought of that when playing around but didn't think it would hold up! How embarrassing, will accept shortly.

Comment: Is there an official name for this?

Comment: @Luka Glad to help! A couple of things you can try with problems like this: (1) look at extreme cases, e.g., what if $x=y$? what if $y=1$?; and (2) look at what happens if you keep one variable fixed and change the other, e.g., try $(x,y) = (5,1), (5,2), \ldots, (5,5)$.

Comment: @Luka I think the official name is *subtraction*. ;)

Comment: Yes, great advice! Thanks.